# Saving checkbox text value to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I've been trying to figure out a good solution all day and believe I'm getting close, but I can't figure out the final solution. What I'm trying to do is save the selected (only the selected) text values of checkboxes into an array so I can eventually save it to a database. Now I'm able to do it if I do the following:

```
yourArray.push($('label[for=checkbox3]').text());
```

However, I want to avoid using specific 'for=checkbox3' and just automatically get the text value for those selected checkboxes. Once I have it working properly I'll be saving the array content into local storage. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<form role="form" action="" class="margin-top-fortypx">
   <div class="checkbox checkbox-container">
      <label class="checkbox-label" for="checkbox1">
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="type" class="remove-bootstrap checkbox-circle margin-right checkbox-js" value="true" />
          Option #1
       </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-container">
       <label class="checkbox-label" for="checkbox2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="type" class="remove-bootstrap checkbox-circle margin-right checkbox-js" value="true" />
           Option #2
        </label>
     </div> 
  </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function jobType() {

  // Not trying to do this for the 6+ checkboxes
  // var text = $('label[for=checkbox1]').text();
  // var textt = $('label[for=checkbox2]').text();
  // var texttt = $('label[for=checkbox3]').text();
  var yourArray = [];

  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
    yourArray.push($('label[for=checkbox3]').text());
  });

  alert(yourArray);

  localStorage.setItem('jobs-selected', text);
  var job = localStorage.getItem("jobs-selected");

}
```

**Image of current checkbox form:**

[image]

My goal is this: `yourArray = [Option #1, Option #2, Option#4, Option #8]` depending on random selection from the user.

I hope I explained it well enough for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is each checkbox guaranteed to be inside its associated label?

Comment: @auxtaco Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would to just find the form and all the inputs in the form this way you will have all the values of the form you can then potential do anything you want with the data.

You should probably also use the value instead of text that what is there for. The value should not just be true. Basically on radios and checkboxes you check that it is checked and then use the value for the value.

HTML

```
<form id="input-form" role="form" action="" class="margin-top-fortypx">
   <div class="checkbox checkbox-container">
      <label class="checkbox-label" for="checkbox1">
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="type" class="remove-bootstrap checkbox-circle margin-right checkbox-js" value="Option #2" checked="true"/>
          Option #1
       </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-container">
       <label class="checkbox-label" for="checkbox2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="type" class="remove-bootstrap checkbox-circle margin-right checkbox-js" value="Option #1" />
           Option #2
        </label>
     </div> 
  </form>
```

Javascript

```
var form = document.getElementById('input-form');

var myArray = [];
form.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function (input) {
  if(input.type === 'checkbox' && input.checked) {
    myArray.push(input.value);
  }
})

console.log(myArray)
```

http://jsbin.com/peficoseva/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for the help Enjayy. I've attempted this solution but got the following error: client-info.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at jobType (client-info.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (test2.html:153)

Comment: @mur7ay That seems a little odd, did you add the id to the form in the html? I also edited the post with a link to jsbin so you can see it in action

Comment: Ah, that's what I missed. I didn't have the id in the form.

Comment: I'm just curious now, and you don't have to answer, but how is this option better than what AuxTaco provided above?

Comment: @mur7ay I think the only thing that makes this slightly better is using the value for each checkbox option instead of relying on the text content. Also this solution allows you to get all inputs inside of the specified form and doesn't also rely on the label being wrapped around the input. This ideally could cut a lot of refactor work that may happen in the future if you decide edit the structure of the html this only relies on inputs inside of a tag with an ID of 'input-form' like he asked "is each checkbox guaranteed to be inside its associated label" this solution would hold up if it wasn't

Answer (score 1):

As each checkbox is inside its label and you appear to be using jQuery, you can use [`$.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest `<label>` above each checkbox in the DOM:

```
yourArray = $('input:checkbox[name=type]:checked')
  .closest('label')
  .get()
  .map(label => label.textContent);
```

Equivalent vanilla JS:

```
yourArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=type]:checked'))
  .map(check => check.closest('label').textContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="grup_check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="buah" class="buah" value="apple"> Apple<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="buah" class="buah" value="banana"> Banana<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="buah" class="buah" value="orange"> Orange<br>
    </form>

<script>
 let arrOfCheckbox = []
 let x = document.getElementsByName('buah').forEach((item,index)=>{
    
    item.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        arrOfCheckbox[index] = (e.srcElement.checked) ? e.srcElement.value : '' ;
        let ff = arrOfCheckbox.filter((x)=>{
            return x != ''
        })
        console.log(ff);
    })

 })
 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```